# What to call it when someone takes something the most negative possible way

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

Is there a word for the situation when someone takes something said in the most negative possible way, basically stretching what is said to fit the negative meaning that they desire it to mean.

Example:

"Maybe we shouldn't hang out."

to mean:

"I never want to talk to you again, you are cut from my life."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd call it [**pessimism**](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pessimism?q=Pessimism). Or even **extreme pessimism**.

Answer (score 17):

I think that "melodramatic" would work well here.

> Characteristic of melodrama, esp. in being exaggerated, sensationalized, or overemotional.

For example:

> Dave: I can't come with you on Friday.
>
> Lynn: You never, ever want to see me!
>
> Dave: Oh, don't be so melodramatic!

Comment: In such a case, I'd say their given reaction is melodramatic, not their interpretation of the initial statement.

Comment: I disagree. For my money, a *melodramatic* person is one who [makes a song and dance about something](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+a+song+and+dance+about) - not necessarily always negatively. I feel the etymology (Greek ***mélos** = song + **drame** drama*) supports that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I do agree but, to me, the OP's example screamed melodrama.

Comment: @Ste: I understand that, which is why I didn't actually *downvote* your answer - it could fit OP's context. But it could also fit if the exchange had been *"Maybe we should hang out together **more**."* - *"Oooh! Yes please! Maybe get married at the weekend if it's still going well by then!"*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Absolutely. At least our dialogue is here for posterity. :)

Answer (score 7):

I feel the most appropriate description of this situation is ***over-reacting*** or ***over-reaction***.

Answer (score 6):

A common way of describing someone who always exaggerates the downside of any situation and/or chooses to interpret everything pessimistically, is to say...

> [He](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22he%27s%20so%20negative%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)/[she](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22she%27s%20so%20negative%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is so [**negative**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/negative).

Answer (score 1):

I would call it exaggeration. Though it doesn't have any negative connotations attached, but I feel this word fits in the most here.